is there any other way to do dynamic form validation in flutter
class ExperienceForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isShowCurrentlyWorkingHere;
  final bool isShowCheckbox;
  final WorkExperienceModel? workExperienceModel;
  final VoidCallback previousExperienceOnTap;

  ExperienceForm({
    super.key,
    this.isShowCurrentlyWorkingHere = false,
    this.isShowCheckbox = false,
    this.workExperienceModel,
    required this.previousExperienceOnTap,
  });
  var state = _ExperienceForm();
  @override
  State<ExperienceForm> createState() {
    return state;
  }

  bool isValid() => state.validate();
}

It is suppose to return like this
 State<ExperienceForm> createState() {
        return _ExperienceForm();
  }

But the problem is I have one continue button in the parent widget, during ontap i will loop all the List of ExperienceForm widget and call the isValid(). This isValid calls a method which looks like this
  bool validate() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState!.validate();
    if (isValid) {
     
      _formKey.currentState!.save();
    }
    return isValid;
  }

But currentState is null. so getting null exception. when i store it in a variable like this
 var state = _ExperienceForm();

It is working fine but after some period of time it is throwing heap space overflow. I tried using listview with addautomaticalive params and AutomaticKeepAlive mixins but createState method is keep on disposing and creating the state object which results in null when accessing form key.
